# Android: Autocomplete Text View

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am developing an android application that uses Google Places autocomplete.

When I select an item from the autocomplete list view the whole string is shown in the autocomplete text view and when it doesn't fit in one row, the text view automatically gets bigger to fit the whole string.

I do not want that to happen, I want the text view to stay the same size, it doesn't matter if the whole string can't be seen. How can I do this??

Another question about autocomplete text view. I need to have a button next to the text view so the user can submit the search. The list view for suggestions is only as wide as the autocomplete text view, it doesn't fill the whole width of the screen, because there is a button on the right side of the text view. Can I make the suggestions list view fill the width of the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I go with `android:singleLine` as refer to [singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine).
2. If you want to make suggestion `listview` you can use these attribute `android:dropDownWidth="xx dp"` refer here [android:dropDownWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android%3adropDownWidth) . You should calculate screen size at runtime to get the right value.

Other attribute can help you align dropdown listview `android:dropDownHorizontalOffset` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#attr_android%3adropDownHorizontalOffset)

Comment: thanks a lot!! The attribute android:dropDownWidth works perfect. I set the value to "match_parent" and the dropdown list fills the entire screen width.

Answer (score 0):

Try [maxWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amaxWidth)

```
android:maxWidth

Makes the TextView be at most this many pixels wide.

Must be a dimension value, which is a floating point number appended with a unit such
as "14.5sp". Available units are: px (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp 
(scaled pixels based on preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters).

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or
theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol maxWidth.

Related Methods

setMaxWidth(int)
```

EDIT - you can use [android:imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aimeOptions) with `actionGo` to add the "go" button to the popup keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the text view to stay the same size, it doesn't matter if the
>   whole string can't be seen

You can use `android:singleLine` as refer to [singleLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine).

> Can I make the suggestions list view fill the width of the screen?

Don't think you can by using AutoCompleteTextView. You can go for User : **Bill Gary** suggestion, by adding an `android:imeOptions="actionGo"`, you can have a `Go` button on soft keyboard. And then, on your Activity, add `OnEditorActionListener` to your AutoCompleteTextView :

```
    actv.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "GO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AutoCompleteTextView a=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
String s[]={"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Months"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,s);
a.setAdapter(adapter);
```